# junior professor's strategy of postdoc recruitment

Tags: postdocs

If the professor has 15 publications and a postdoc applicant has 10 papers, will the professor think the applicant is too strong to colloborate well as to not obey the professor's ideas all the time?

Answer (score 5):

Being a young professor I will not hesitate to hire an applicant with a profile even stronger than mine; especially, if I feel that postdoctoral candidate has good plans which will be beneficial for my research group. My own Postdoctoral experience was very good, my professor never treated me as student, rather a peer colleague. 
 Also, in my opinion a professor who want an obedient postdoc is not a professor I would ever consider to work with. In academics healthy criticism is the best feedback on your work and the way to improve.

Comment: This is the correct way that a professor should handle the situation. However, I think that there definitely could be professors that act in the way that the OP is worried about